# react hooks dispatch action with use dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I have a problem calling my action using usedispatch

he arrives on my action but for some reason he does not pass on my return.
stop here:     console.log('here is get all products');
and no go to my getallproducts:

```
export const getAllProducts = () => {
    console.log('here is get all products');
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
        api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data))})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
    }
}
```

my reducer:

```
import {FETCH_FAIL, FETCH_SUCESS, FETCH_LOADING} from '../../actions/fetch/actionType';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: [],
    fn:[],
    mw:[],
    ft:[],
    ww:[],
    bs:[],
    stattrek:[],
    normal:[],
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          filteredProducts: action.data.listProducts,
          products: action.data.listProducts,
          fn: action.data.fn,
          mw: action.data.mw,
          ft: action.data.ft,
          ww: action.data.ww,
          bs: action.data.bs,
          stattrek: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 1),
          normal: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 2)
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

my container:

```
import styles from "../assets/cardStyle";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {useEffect, useCallback} from "react";
import { getAllProducts } from '../store/actions/fetch/index'
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Cards() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const loadProducts= useCallback(async () => {
        dispatch(getAllProducts());
        }, [dispatch]);

        useEffect(() => {
            loadProducts();
            }, [loadProducts]);

    const products = useSelector(state => {
    })

    products.map(product=>(
        <div>
        <Container fixed>
            <Grid container direction="row" >
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent className= {classes.cardCarousel}>
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook together with your
                                guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the mussels, if you like.
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    </div> 
    ))

    return (
        {products}
    );
}
```

I can't imagine where I'm going wrong
it calls my getAllProducts but does not enter my redux

Comment: dispatch is not available in the scope of that function. Pass it to the function as an argument.

Comment: how i can make this? i need pass on my useDispatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create higher-order functions like you do in `getAllProducts()` returning another function you need to call that function and pass `dispatch` as the first argument.

```
const loadProducts= useCallback(() => {
    /**
     * first call returns a function from getAllProducts
     * second will call it and we pass dispatch as the first argument 
     */ 
    getAllProducts()(dispatch);
}, [dispatch, getAllProducts]);
```

Or you can simply pass `dispatch` in the first function and call it right away:

```
export const getAllProducts = (dispatch) => {
    console.log('here is get all products');
    dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
    // fetching data
    api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data))})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
}
// ...
const loadProducts= useCallback(() => {
    /**
     * first call pass dispatch as the first argument
     */ 
    getAllProducts(dispatch);
}, [dispatch, getAllProducts]);
```

Comment: thank you bro,
could you ask me one more question?

I save my state with:

     const products = useSelector (state => state.data)

but when i try to give the .map i have error of .map is not function

Comment: i think the problem might be you yet haven't received the data and it's `undefined` you can check that then call `.map` on it.

Comment: The problem was, I wasn't passing an array

but now I passed an array and got this error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, float, price, id_sub, subcategory, id_types, type, id_ext, outer, img, description}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: You're trying to render an object as a child. While in dev you can just wrap it in `JSON.stringify(product)` to see the content.

Comment: Whats the win here using useCallback? Why do you need a stable reference here?

Answer (score 1):

You could just go ahead and import the `useDispatch` hook in the file located here `../store/actions/fetch/index`

similar to the way you did in your other file

Comment: Instead of using useDispatch in my container use in my action?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Yes like you use the dispatch in your action that way your container focus on component logic.

Comment: Don't do this. Hooks are supposed to be called unconditionally at the beginning of each components, if at some point you need to change your logic of when to call `getAllProducts()` then `useDispatch()` will be called conditionally and will definitely break your logic.